# How can I always spawn mpv with no borders in Xmonad?

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, xmonad

I'm having an issue with `mpv` because of the `xmonad` borders and I'd like to be able to always start `mpv`, floating, with no borders at all, and also to keep the functionality of `mpv` keybindings as is by default.

**Note: I know that as my current `.xmonad` config file is, I can go full screen in `mpv` with `meta+b` then `meta+f` but I'd like to be able to use only the default `f` keybinding from `mpv` to do go full screen and have no borders. The last method currently doesn't work.**

##### Would that be possible?

If yes, how do I need to modify my `.xmonad` config file?

This is my current .xmonad confhg file

```
import System.IO
import System.Exit

import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.SetWMName
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers(doFullFloat, doCenterFloat, isFullscreen, isDialog)
import XMonad.Config.Desktop
import XMonad.Config.Azerty
import XMonad.Util.Run(spawnPipe)
import XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig (additionalKeys, additionalMouseBindings)
import XMonad.Actions.CycleWS
import XMonad.Hooks.UrgencyHook
import qualified Codec.Binary.UTF8.String as UTF8

import XMonad.Layout.Spacing
import XMonad.Layout.Gaps
import XMonad.Layout.ResizableTile
import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders
import XMonad.Layout.Fullscreen (fullscreenFull)
import XMonad.Layout.Cross(simpleCross)
import XMonad.Layout.Spiral(spiral)
import XMonad.Layout.ThreeColumns
import XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle
import XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle.Instances
import XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens


import XMonad.Layout.CenteredMaster(centerMaster)

import Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Control.Monad (liftM2)
import qualified DBus as D
import qualified DBus.Client as D


myStartupHook = do
    spawn "$HOME/.xmonad/scripts/autostart.sh"
    setWMName "LG3D"

-- colours
normBord = "#4c566a"
focdBord = "#5e81ac"
fore     = "#DEE3E0"
back     = "#282c34"
winType  = "#c678dd"

--mod4Mask= super key
--mod1Mask= alt key
--controlMask= ctrl key
--shiftMask= shift key

myModMask = mod4Mask
encodeCChar = map fromIntegral . B.unpack
myFocusFollowsMouse = True
myBorderWidth = 2
myWorkspaces    = ["\61612","\61899","\61947","\61635","\61502","\61501","\61705","\61564","\62150","\61872"]
--myWorkspaces    = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
--myWorkspaces    = ["I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX","X"]

myBaseConfig = desktopConfig

-- window manipulations
myManageHook = composeAll . concat $
    [ [isDialog --> doCenterFloat]
    , [className =? c --> doCenterFloat | c <- myCFloats]
    , [title =? t --> doFloat | t <- myTFloats]
    , [resource =? r --> doFloat | r <- myRFloats]
    , [resource =? i --> doIgnore | i <- myIgnores]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61612" | x <- my1Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61899" | x <- my2Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61947" | x <- my3Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61635" | x <- my4Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61502" | x <- my5Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61501" | x <- my6Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61705" | x <- my7Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61564" | x <- my8Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\62150" | x <- my9Shifts]
    -- , [(className =? x <||> title =? x <||> resource =? x) --> doShiftAndGo "\61872" | x <- my10Shifts]
    ]
    where
    -- doShiftAndGo = doF . liftM2 (.) W.greedyView W.shift
    myCFloats = ["Arandr", "Arcolinux-calamares-tool.py", "Arcolinux-tweak-tool.py", "Arcolinux-welcome-app.py", "Galculator", "feh", "Xfce4-terminal"]
    myTFloats = ["Downloads", "Save As..."]
    myRFloats = []
    myIgnores = ["desktop_window"]
    -- my1Shifts = ["Chromium", "Vivaldi-stable", "Firefox"]
    -- my2Shifts = []
    -- my3Shifts = ["Inkscape"]
    -- my4Shifts = []
    -- my5Shifts = ["Gimp", "feh"]
    -- my6Shifts = ["vlc", "mpv"]
    -- my7Shifts = ["Virtualbox"]
    -- my8Shifts = ["Thunar"]
    -- my9Shifts = []
    -- my10Shifts = ["discord"]




myLayout = spacingRaw True (Border 0 5 5 5) True (Border 5 5 5 5) True $ mkToggle (NBFULL ?? NOBORDERS ?? EOT) $ tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| spiral (6/7)  ||| ThreeColMid 1 (3/100) (1/2) ||| noBorders Full
    where
        tiled = Tall nmaster delta tiled_ratio
        nmaster = 1
        delta = 3/100
        tiled_ratio = 1/2


myMouseBindings (XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modMask}) = M.fromList $

    -- mod-button1, Set the window to floating mode and move by dragging
    [ ((modMask, 1), (\w -> focus w >> mouseMoveWindow w >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- mod-button2, Raise the window to the top of the stack
    , ((modMask, 2), (\w -> focus w >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- mod-button3, Set the window to floating mode and resize by dragging
    , ((modMask, 3), (\w -> focus w >> mouseResizeWindow w >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this issue with

```
lessBorders Never $ avoidStruts
```

myLayout

```
myLayout = BO.lessBorders BO.Never $ avoidStruts (full ||| tiled ||| grid ||| bsp)
  where
    
      -- full
     full = renamed [Replace "Full"] 
          $ BO.noBorders (Full)
      
      --- tiled
     tiled = renamed [Replace "Tall"] 
           $ spacingRaw True (Border 10 0 10 0) True (Border 0 10 0 10) True
           -- $ spacingRaw True (Border 0 5 5 5) True (Border 5 5 5 5) True 
           $ ResizableTall 1 (3/100) (1/2) []
      -- grid
    
     grid = renamed [Replace "Grid"] 
          $ spacingRaw True (Border 10 0 10 0) True (Border 0 10 0 10) True 
          $ Grid (16/10)
    
     -- bsp
     bsp = renamed [Replace "BSP"] 
         $ emptyBSP
```

main

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    dbus <- D.connectSession
    -- Request access to the DBus name
    D.requestName dbus (D.busName_ "org.xmonad.Log")
        [D.nameAllowReplacement, D.nameReplaceExisting, D.nameDoNotQueue]

    
    
    xmonad $ withUrgencyHook LibNotifyUrgencyHook $ ewmh desktopConfig
        { manageHook = ( isFullscreen --> doFullFloat ) <+> manageDocks <+> myManageHook <+> manageHook desktopConfig
        , startupHook        = myStartupHook
        , layoutHook         = myLayout
        , handleEventHook    = handleEventHook desktopConfig
        , workspaces         = myWorkspaces
        , borderWidth        = myBorderWidth
        , terminal           = myTerminal
        , modMask            = myModMask
        , normalBorderColor  = normBord
        , focusedBorderColor = focdBord
        , logHook            = updatePointer (0.25, 0.25) (0.25, 0.25)
        , keys = myKeys
        , mouseBindings = myMouseBindings
        }
```

and completely rebuilding by `xmonad.sh`

##### See [my related answer on this topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698139/439306), it fixes the issue presented in this question as well.